# ORA-00942: Table or View does not exist. SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

This might be duplicate Title. I am using SQL Developer 4.1.3. I am trying this [LINK](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLServerMigration/SQLServerMigration.htm) to migrate a database but I am having a trouble in Migrating steps. It says ORA-00942: Table or View does not exist.

[See this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhTLd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Things I notice from you description:

1. That link you posted in your question is for SQL Developer Version 3.0 you have a much higher version
2. From that error it appears that you are missing the Oracle Tables maybe you need to tell it to create tables in one of the screens/options somewhere. Cant tell without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: Don't know what to do now :) because I am new to oracle but willing to learn.